# Entry into US with unpaid medical bills and ticket for careless driving

Tags: usa, legal, customs-and-immigration

While on vacation in the US last year, my wife and I was in a traffic accident. My wife had to spend more than a week in hospital before we could fly home. Our insurance is covering everything, but we keep receiving more bills in the mail. We are forwarding the bills to our insurance company, who tells us that they are taking care of them, but they are probably not paying them immediately (I expect there are a lot of paperwork involved). We can see that some of the invoices have strange addresses on them and have taken a long time to reach us, so we are a bit worried that there might be others that haven't reached us yet.

Also, since the accident was partly my fault, I received a ticket for careless driving, which I have paid.

We are going back to the US in a few weeks on vacation. Can any of this give us problems in immigration or elsewhere? Is there anything we should do or special papers we should bring?

Comment: I really doubt if you will have any problems, but just in case I would take the paperwork to show that you have paid the ticket and that you have insurance paying for the medical bills.

Comment: "Careless driving" or "reckless driving"?

Comment: @Karlson: I believe it was *careless* driving. I changed lanes on the highway without noticing another car.

Comment: @Traveller I don't know of any state giving "careless driving" but if you paid it you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: "Careless driving" sounds like a short way of describing "Failure to give Full time and Attention".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Unpaid debts are not an issue for immigration, so even if there are some bills still outstanding immigration are neither going to know that they exist, or care at all about it.

The careless driving ticket may show up on your record that immigration can see, but presuming it is just a simple careless driving ticket then it's nothing to worry about. The exception here would be if the ticket include anything related to a "controlled substance". ie, if they charged you with being under the influence of alcohol (DUI) or drugs at the time of the accident.  Presuming that's not the case (and I'm sure it's not, if only because your insurance probably wouldn't have covered the bills if it was!) then you're set!

Answer (score 3):

No, shouldn't be a problem. Looks like you're doing everything right, you paid your ticket and you're taking care of your bills. Why are you even worried?