# Travelling back to US with unpaid hospital bills

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, insurance

About a year ago I visited my US, and needed emergency treatment for a small accident. My insurance company refused to pay for it, and I am unable to cover the bill. it's not a large amount, but large enough.

Should I want to re-visit the US, will I have any issues at immigration while getting in?

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6543/entry-into-us-with-unpaid-medical-bills-and-ticket-for-careless-driving